# Eisenstein polynomial of totally ramified extension over $p$-adic field

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, computational-number-theory, factorization, ramification

Let $p\geq 3$ be a prime number, $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with no non-trivial unramified subextension, $f(x)$ be an irreducible monic polynomial in $\mathcal{O}_K[x]$, making $L=K[x]/(f(x))$ a Galois totally and wildly ramified extension of $K$. How can we find an Eisenstein $E(x)\in\mathcal{O}_K[x]$ that generates $L$, i.e. $L=K[x]/(E(x))$?
As far as I know, there are two ways to do this:

1. When the MAGMA system factorizing a polynomial $f$ over $p$-adic field $K$, it has an option to generate the field $K[x]/(g(x))$ for every irreducible factor $g$ of $f$ (thanks for Professor T. Dokchitser telling me this). This field is represented as a totally ramified extension over an unramified extensin over $K$, where the totally ramified part is represented as an Eisenstein polynomial. The factorization relies on S. Pauli's Round Four algorithm, which provides some additional arithmetic information of $g$ to produce the corresponding Eisenstein polynomial. However, this method (for generating Eisenstein polynomial) is not well documented. Professor Pauli claims that any Okutsu-Montes algorithm can be used to construct such an Eisenstein polynomial, but I don't know how to do it in detail.
2. The third-party SageMath package [Henselization](https://github.com/MCLF/henselization) implemented by Julian Rüth can [generate](https://github.com/MCLF/henselization/blob/bded9bafb454d12223f6b54b132a5b1df353d5ec/henselization/sage/rings/padics/henselization/henselization.py#L1444) such an Eisenstein polynomial for the totally ramified extension. His code is based on the "limit valuation" theory by MacLane, which differs from the traditional implementation of $p$-adic arithmetic.

My question is: whether there exists a relatively self-contained algorithm to obtain this goal, or this question is essentially related to some complicated theories, like the Okutsu-Montes algorithm and MacLane's valuation theory?

I'd like to view this question as an algebraic number theory question rather than a computational one, since the time complexity is not the main concern here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a super naive algorithm, assuming that you know some uniformizer $\pi_K$:

Let $\alpha\in L$ be a root of $f$ and $N=\deg(f),M=[K:\Bbb{Q}_p]$. Normalize the valuation such that $v(\pi_K)=N$.

Try each $d\ge 1$ and each element $\bar{b}$ of $(\Bbb{Z}[\pi_K]/(p^d,\pi_K^{dM}))^N$, if $d$ is large enough then there will be one $\bar{b}$ such that $v(\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \bar{b}_n \alpha^n)=v(p^e)+1$ with $e< d$.

ie. taking any $b\in \Bbb{Z}[\pi_K]^N$ such that $b=\bar{b}\bmod (p^d,\pi_K^{md})$ you'll have that $$\det(x-\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} b_n \alpha^n}{p^e}\in End_K(L))$$ is the monic degree $N$ Eisenstein polynomial in $O_K[x]$ you are asking for.

Of course $\pi_K$ can be found with the same algorithm in the first place.

Note that knowing $\pi_K$ is useful mainly for checking if $h=\det(x-\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} b_n \alpha^n}{p^e}\in End_K(L))$ is Eisenstein. From any basis of $K/\Bbb{Q}_p$, for $d>l$ large enough you can enumerate the elements of $p^l O_K/p^d O_K$, and you can check instead if $\det(x-\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} b_n \alpha^n}{p^e}\in End_{\Bbb{Q}_p}(L))$ is Eisenstein, if it is then $\det(x-\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} b_n \alpha^n}{p^e}\in End_K(L))$ will be Eisenstein as well.

Comment: So basically it's a brute-force search?